# Dynamo DB import from S3 without id

Tags: csv, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to dynamo DB, I am trying to import (using Import from S3 in dashboard), a generic csv.
The csv has no unique id, so import gives error.

Is it possibile to import csv asking dynamo to generate id (and id column) when importing?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could preprocess the file(s).